# How to read only those records which have no lock on them?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table from which I select specific records and update them.Now I want to run two separate programs to do this job.
The table is `submission` which stores the program submissions of a contest.It has an
attribute `status` which is initially `Queued` and is later changed to `Wrong Answer`,`Accepted` etc.So my program reads those records which have status as `Queued` and evaluates them. 
Now if I run this program on two separate terminals say `program_1 and program_2`. If `program_1` reads a record with `Queued` status then I don't want `program_2` to read it because it will mean re-evaluation of a submission.This defeats my purpose of parallel evaluation.Also If I put a lock on the record read by `program_1` it will solve the problem.But then `program_2` might have to wait for the lock to be released even when `program_1`
is evaluating the submission and after it releases the lock `program_2` has nothing to do with this submission as its status would be something else from `Queued` as it would be already evaluated by `program_1`.This again defeats purpose of parallel evaluation somehow.
How do I get around this problem??

Comment: Can you try to divide your rows in equals piece `nbPerProg = (nb_rows / nb_prog)` ? keep the offset and use LIMIT clause like  `LIMIT offset, nbPerProg`. Each program will have its own part of your table to check.

Comment: @Marcassin I thought something similar to it , but how to handle the case where one program stops abruptly all the solutions of one particular kind won't be evaluated?

Comment: In this case about 2 solutions : 1) depends on your program language, but if you can handle exception, catch error during processing on a row and keep the current ID or current offset, and re-run the program with LIMIT (offset + currOffset), (nbPerProg - currOffset) to finish unprocessed rows.
2) For each row processed, update a DATETIME column with current time, or number of your processing, or ... in order to know which ones has been processed during last runs of your programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested *only* in the solution for exactly two programs, how about you just sort the table by its primary key, and have `program_1` start from the top of the list and `program_2` start from the bottom? That limits your duplication-of-effort to at most one record (the one where the two programs' efforts "meet in the middle"). And if one program dies after only a few records, the other one will be able to finish the work.

(Of course, if one program dies after only a few records, odds are that there's a severe enough bug that the other program will die soon too.)

FWIW, I recommend not trying to do this at all. Having two processes fight over an undifferentiated workload is never a good idea. If you want to speed up the processing, then do the query on one thread and then explicitly split up the work among several other threads. (You can do the same approach by forking new processes instead of spawning new threads; or even by making RPCs to other physical machines; but that *really* seems like overkill to me.)

I.e., instead of

```
L = result_of_SQL_query();
worker1.process(L) & worker2.process(L);
```

you should be doing

```
L = result_of_SQL_query();
L1 = first_half_of(L);
L2 = second_half_of(L);
worker1.process(L1) & worker2.process(L2);
```

If you're worried that `worker1` might die, then you'll need some way for the parent process to detect that a child has died, query for its remaining workload, and then redistribute that workload to another child.